# You do not have an implicit Application in scope: PlayFramework with Oracle

Tags: oracle, scala, playframework

Getting following error when trying to access oracle DataSource using play framework:

```
sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[You do not have an implicit Application in scope. If you want to bring
the current running Application into context, just add import play.api.Play.current]
```

build.properties:

```
sbt.version=0.12.2
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(.....basic))))"
db.default.user="username"
db.default.pass="passowrd"
```

Controller Application.scala is as follows:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.db._


object Application extends Controller {

  val d = DB.getDataSource();

  def index = Action { request => Ok("something") } 

}
```

What is causing this issue. Everything looks correct to me.

**FYI. play! 2.1.4 (using Java 1.6.0_24 and Scala 2.10.0)**

-Thanks

Answer (score 19):

The error message is actually telling you what to do: *You do not have an implicit Application in scope. If you want to bring the current running Application into context, just add import play.api.Play.current*.

```
import play.api.Play.current
```

This is what the getDataSource method look like:

```
  def getDataSource(name: String = "default")(implicit app: Application): DataSource = app.plugin[DBPlugin].map(_.api.getDataSource(name)).getOrElse(error)
```

As you can see it takes an implicit Application in the second argument list and the compiler is looking for an implicitly declared Application which can be found in the import.

Comment: The app works fine if I remove following line : "val d = DB.getDataSource();"  from controller, even without the import you mentioned. If I put the import though, the application breaks. I am not sure why would I bring application into context, because everything just runs fine if "val d = DB.getDataSource();" is removed.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I can't answer why you want to use the DB in the controller like you do.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why this happens.

Comment: play.api.Play.current is deprecated in Play 2.5

Comment: Now it says "method current in object Play is deprecated: This is a static reference to application, use DI instead".

Comment: @JulienD Yes, this answer does not apply to newer versions of Play where it should be using DI instead. Look for answers elsewhere.