# play 2.5 DB issue - Use dependency injection

Tags: mysql, jdbc, playframework, playframework-2.3

**Issue:**

I am facing the below issue in play 2.5 while compilation.

> You do not have an implicit Application in scope. If you want to
>   bring the current running Application into context, please use
>   dependency injection.
>
> Getting issue in line - DB.withConnection {^

**Code snippet:**

```
object User {
  def getId(emailid: String): Option[Int] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
      SQL("select id from user where email = {email}").on(
        'email -> emailid).as(SqlParser.scalar[Int].singleOpt)
    }
  }
}
```

How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem you met is like this:

[You do not have an implicit Application in scope: PlayFramework with Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834723/you-do-not-have-an-implicit-application-in-scope-playframework-with-oracle)

have a try that import the package of 'play.api.Play.current', namely add the following in your code file

```
import play.api.Play.current
```

have a good luck

Comment: While this solves the issue right now, it will lead to a deprecation warning in play 2.5. Once you upgrade to play 2.6 you will be forced to use dependency injection.

Comment: can someone explain how this is done using dependency injection?

Answer (score 4):

Make `User` a class and inject it where you need it.

`class User @Inject() (db: Database) { ..}`

And in your controller:

`class MyController @Inject() (user: User) extends Controller {
  // ..
  user.getId
  // ..
}`

Read more here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase

Comment: How to instantiate the User class in a trait as a implicit lazy val ?

Comment: you could define the user as a `def` and have the actual value in the subclass.